# Sed causes abrupt cut off to files

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm using Sed (on Ubuntu) and I need it to remove a handpicked selection of poor text sequences from 2 files (the same text in 2 different languages) that make the sentence hard to read by a computer. Up until now, it had worked perfectly on all my files. But, for some reason, now it abruptly stops at a certain line every time. No error is given, nothing to even hint something has gone wrong (which makes me feel nothing has gone wrong, and I just coded it wrong).

Here is my script:

```
en=.en
ga=.ga

src=/home/justin/opus.txt/LanEub

echo "Removing poor sequences..."
for l in $en $ga; do
        echo $src$l

    cat $src$l |\
    #Removes starting year (e.g. 1994)
    sed -e 's/^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]://g' |\
    #Removes anything like (a) at the start
    sed -e 's/^(.) //g' |\
    #Removes anything like '2 .'
    sed -e 's/. *\.//g' |\
    #Deletes line with anything like '2074/203/EEC'
    sed -e '/[[:digit:]]*\/[[:digit:]]*\/E*C/d' |\
    sed -e '/OJ No L/d' |\
    #Removes ending ':' or ';'
    sed -e 's/:$//g' |\
    sed -e 's/;$//g' |\
    #Removes anything like '20.04.'
    sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.//g' |\
    #Deletes line containing excessive dots '....'
    sed -e '/\.{4}/d' |\
    #sed -e 's/—■//g' |\
    #Removes starting punctuation like '* '
    sed -e 's/^[[:punct:]]* //g' |\
    sed -e '/ TEC)$/d' |\
    sed -e '/ CCE)$/d' |\
    sed -e '/ TEU)$/d' |\
    sed -e '/ CAE)$/d' |\
    #sed -e 's/•//g' |\
    #sed -e 's/©//g' |\
    #Removes unnecessary starting space 
    sed -e 's/^ //g' > $src$l
done
```

There are 3 commented sed commands. I thought the unusual characters may have caused it but that's not it. I've also tried replacing '[[:space:]]' with actual spaces.
To summarise, the script goes through a doc in each of the two languages, trying to remove these sequences that add noise to the text. Here is where it stops:

**In English:**

> —improvement in particular of the working envi

**In Irish:**

> Ina thionscnamh ADAPT cuireann s **\C3**

Where **\c3** is added in by sed.

Here is the text that follows it in the original versions of the files, that gets cut off, in case it's of any use:

**English**

> —improvement in particular of the working environment to protectworkers’health and safety;
>
> —the information and consultation of workers;
>
> —theintegrationofpersonsexcludedfromthelabourmarket,with-out prejudice to Article 150;
>
> —equality between men and women with regard to labour marketopportunities and treatment at work.

**Irish**

> Ina thionscnamh ADAPT cuireann sé roímhe bunsraith do mhogalra náisiúnta a chur chun tacú le oiliúint oilíúnóírí in Éirinn.
>
> Ceapadh an Tionsnamh Pobail URBAN chun dui i ngleic le fadhbanna uirbeacha ar bhealach comhtháthaithe.
>
> Roghnaíodh tri ceantar in Éirinn chun maoiniú a fháil i rith na tréimhse ó 1996 - 1999.
>
> Le tacaiocht ó URBAN, forbraíodh lonaid/Spásanna Fíontraíochta i ngach ceann de na tri cheantar.

If anyone needs the whole file, I can post it, I just don't want to dump the whole file if it isn't necessary.

Any help is appreciated,

Justin

Comment: you're overwriting the file that's being read.  Use a temp file to store the output instead.  Others: `l` is a very poor variable name.  You're using excessive pipes, all can be compressed into one script.  Double quote variables, filenames. You don't need line continuation '\' after pipe....

Comment: @karakfa Thanks, the temp file did it, and also changing the variable name. Shell isn't really something I know a lot of, may I ask what you mean by pipes?

Comment: `|` is the pipe, you're invoking `sed` too many times unnecesarily...

Comment: [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) lets you stack commands - just separate with semicolons - e.g. `sed 's/^(.) //g; s/. *\.//g; "$src$l"`. In non-GNU versions you can just use newlines instead, inside the quoted `sed` script. One call to the executable is enough, and vastly better than 15. Likewise, you don't need `cat`, `sed` can read the file directly. You should probably also look at the `-E` option to simplify so many patterns down into just a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you are writing the same file as you are reading.
Everything in your code from `cat $src$l` to the last `> $src$l` happens at the same time... So `cat` starts to read the file but it gets truncated by `>` so it stops as there is nothing else to read.

You need to write to a different (temporary) file instead or use [sponge(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) which is not installed by default.
Example:

```
cat "$src$l" |
sed -e '...' |
sed -e '...' |
sed -e '...' > "$src$l.tmp" && mv "$src$l.tmp" "$src$l"
```

Also, you should not do this:

```
cat $file1 |\
sed -e 'foo' |\
sed -e 'bar' > $file2
```

But this:

```
sed "$file1" -e 'foo' -e 'bar' > "$file2"
```

If you want to skip lines, you can use `\`:

```
sed "$file1" \
  -e 'foo' \
  -e 'bar' > "$file2"
```